# Selecting entries that are numerically close to each other in a database

Tags: sql, ms-access, bioinformatics

Lets say I have a table called ABC in a MS-Access Database.

There are several columns in this table but only two columns are of interest for this question - "Hugo_symbol" and "Start_position". "Hugo_Symbol" has gene names and several lines can have the same Hugo_symbol - meaning this column has duplicate entries. "Start_position" has numbers - anything from 1000 to 100000000.

I want to build a query that returns lines from table ABC that
1) Have the same Hugo_Symbol AND
2) Start_position is within 20 of each other.

For eg., the query should return,

```
Hugo_Symbol         Start_Position

TP53                      987654
TP53                      987660
TP53                      987662
APOB                      12345
APOB                      12350
APOB                      12359
```

because these lines have the same Hugo_Symbol and Start_Position is within 20 of each other.

Is such a query possible? If so, what would the SQL code be?

Comment: `Start_Position` is within 20 of _what_?  A passed in value?  Any other row (with the same `Hugo_Symbol`)?  Would a row containing [`APOB`, `12330`] be included?  What about [`APOB`, `12325`]? Can we get some _starting_ data?  What version of Access?

Comment: Access 2000. Within 20 of "each other". Any other row with the same Hugo_Symbol. Yes, {APOB 12320} would be included, because it is within 20 of {APOB 12345}. Same for {APOB 12325}.. 'Starting data', as in?

Comment: @Shyam_LA - Data in your table that you would expect to get those results from - This should include things like rows you're expecting to **not** be included.  That said, Hans has a point - you really are supposed to put some effort into this yourself.  I initially thought this might require some OLAP functionality (and might be preferred for performance reasons), but it hits me I was thinking about this too hard...

Comment: @HansUp: I agree with your sentiment, but aside from the OP's attitude, I think this is a perfectly legitimate question for SO.  I edited the question to remove the OP's explicit request for copy and paste code because we certainly do not want to encourage that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Access, but this is how I'd approach it with ANSI SQL.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ABC    AS first
INNER JOIN
  ABC    AS second
    ON  second.Hugo_Symbol     = first.Hugo_Symbol
    AND second.Start_Position <= first.Start_Position + 20
    AND second.Start_Position >  first.Start_Position
```

This will potentially return more data that you expect, and potentially a different format that you expect.

```
First.Hugo_Symbol First.Start_Position Second.Hugo_Symbol Second.Start_Position
     TP53              987654                TP53              987660
     TP53              987654                TP53              987662
     TP53              987660                TP53              987662
     APOB              12345                 APOB              12350
     APOB              12350                 APOB              12359
     APOB              12350                 APOB              12359
```

**EDIT:**

The answer above is highly influence with "Each Other".

If you reform the requirements as "all records where another record exists with the same symbol and a position with 20 of it's own position" you could get something like...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ABC     AS data
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM ABC AS lookup
           WHERE lookup.hugo_symbol     = data.hugo_symbol
             AND lookup.start_position >= data.start_position - 20
             AND lookup.start_position <= data.start_position + 20
             AND lookup.start_position <> data.start_position
         )
```

But Access2000 is more limitted that the databases I normally use.  I don't know what Access2000 can and can't do.

Comment: The second code works perfectly. Gives me exactly what I was looking for.. But, there is one issue - I want all the entries with the same Hugo_Symbol to be listed together. My table has 25000 entries, as of now and the query returns 1200 entries but is difficult to make sense of it because of the lack of said grouping. Can they be grouped automatically? Thanks!

Comment: @shyam_LA : Add `ORDER BY data.hugo_symbol, data.start_position`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ABC.Hugo_Symbol, ABC.Start_Position, ABC_1.Start_Position
FROM ABC INNER JOIN ABC AS ABC_1 ON 
   ABC.Hugo_Symbol = ABC_1.Hugo_Symbol AND 
   ABC.Start_Position + 20 >= ABC_1.Start_Position AND
   ABC.Start_Position < ABC_1.Start_Position
```

Comment: Looks like @Dems beat me to it.  And with a more fleshed out answer to boot.