# SQL Server : get a number of values that are numerically close to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm having a bit of a problem finding a solution for my problem, maybe because I don't really know how to express it.

I need to get a number of values from a table or view from a SQL Server database.

The table looks something like this:

```
ID    Column1   Column2    Column3    Column4
1     1         2          41         5
2     3         2          41         5
3     4         2          41         5
4     5         2          41         5
5     6         2          41         5
6     1         5          41         10
7     2         5          41         10
8     3         5          41         10
9     4         5          41         10
```

Let's say I need 3 values (the `ID`) in a row  in return from this table where column3 is a certain (known) value. But the tree values in column1 has to be in a row. (For example ID 2,3 and 4.)

Column2 has to be the same value for all returned ID´s.

Example of returned values:

```
ID 
2
3
4
```

Next time I might need 5 values in a row.

This might need to be made with a stored procedure? Or is it possible to make it as a view?

The closest I have got searching stackoverflow and google is this:
[Selecting entries that are numerically close to each other in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377088/selecting-entries-that-are-numerically-close-to-each-other-in-a-database)

Does anyone have any good idea for my dilemma?

Thanks in advance!

//Andreas

**Edit:** example of returned values

**Edit 2:**
To make this a little bit harder. Is it possible to add another column in #t - c4?
This would be a kind of point system. Each row has its own point. (1-10)
Two possible outputs could be ID 2,3,4 (15points total) and ID 6,7,8 (30 points total).
But the one i want delivered is ID 6,7,8 - due to higer points.

Comment: Please show examples of your desired results.

Comment: The only thing i need as a result is the ID returned as rows. (if i want 3 values, the returned values would be just ID 2, 3 and 4)

Comment: select top <N> ID from YourTable where ID + 1 = Column1. N is your number of records needed. Is that wat you are expecting?

Comment: unfortunately not. The ID has nothing to do with Column 1. Another example of returned values could be ID 6,7 and 8.

Comment: What are the rules for choosing the sequence of rows? Why it's 2,3,4 and not 1,2,3 or 3,4,5? And what's your SQL Server release?

Comment: 3,4,5 is accepted returned values.  But not 1,2,3 because the next value after 1 (column 1) is two, wich is missing.

Comment: Why not allow the groups with Id={2,3,4,5} and Id={6,7,8,9} as valid results ?

Comment: The groups may vary from time to time, as well as the input number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.  I put your data into a table called #t with columns Id, c1, c2, c3, c4.  This would need to be done as a stored procedure with @targetCount as a parameter.  Per your follow-up question, the results are weighted by "points" based upon the values in column c4.

```
DECLARE @targetCount INT = 3, @idList VARCHAR(MAX);

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS IdList, c1, c2, @targetCount AS Lev, c4 as Points
    FROM    #t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cte.IdList + ',' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)), t.c1, t.c2, cte.Lev - 1, cte.Points + t.c4
    FROM    cte
            JOIN #t t ON cte.c1 + 1 = t.c1 AND cte.c2 = t.c2
    WHERE   cte.Lev >= 1
)
SELECT  TOP 1 @idList = ',' + IdList + ','
FROM    cte
WHERE   Lev = 1
ORDER BY Points DESC;

SELECT  Id
FROM    #t
WHERE   @idList LIKE '%,' + CAST(id AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ',%';
```

Comment: This really do the trick! I just had to change the declaration a little bit. Thank you!

Comment: Added a supplementary question in the footer. Could this be possible?

Comment: @Andreas Andersson Try it now.